# How to resize an image attached in the page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, php-5.5

I need to decrease the height of the image attached in the wordpress page. i had tried several methods but i am unable to solve it.It is not getting any change when i am adding image size Topbannerimg in img src.

my wp_query to dispaly image

```
<?php 
$homepage = get_page_by_title('Top Banner');
$attachments = get_posts( array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'post_parent' => $homepage->ID,
) );
if ( $attachments ) {
  echo '<section class="topBanner">';
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { ?>          
      <a href="<?php if($attachment->post_excerpt){echo $attachment->post_excerpt;}else{echo "#";}?>">
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID); ?>">
      </a>

    <?php }
  echo '</section>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

size mentioned in functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'TopBannerImg', 1800, 500, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_get_attachment_image function to display image. Please refer: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/.
Pass image thumbnail name as second paremeter.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code:

First parameter for width and second for height.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 480, 277 ) ); ?>
```